# Rails scope and sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is this code safety from sql injection ?

```
  scope :by_file_name, proc { |file_name| where("source_file ilike '%#{file_name}%'") }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of passing parameter which is safe from sql injection is

```
 scope :by_file_name, proc { |file_name| where("source_file ilike ?", "%#{file_name}%") }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you should do the scope like this:

```
scope :by_file_name, proc { |file_name| where("source_file ilike '%?%'", file_name) }
```

Answer (score 1):

No.

It should be:

```
scope :by_file_name, proc { |file_name| where("source_file ilike ?", file_name) }
```

Comment: This one does not work exactly like my version. It does not search proper records.